# MFMessageComposeViewController not working

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, viewcontroller, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have a simple method that gets one argument and then sends a message. It is not working.

Code:

```
- (void)sendSMS:(NSString *)text {
    MFMessageComposeViewController *viewController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.body = text;
    viewControllerM.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the delegate:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = @"YO";
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"5625555555", nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```