# How do I send message programmatically in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have used the following code but it not worked.

My code is:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
controller.body = @"Check out 'Invite Me' for iOS and be my friend here.";
controller.recipients = arrSelectedPhoneNumbers;
NSLog(@"%@",controller.recipients);
controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
 {
  controller.body = @"Check out 'Invite Me' for iOS and be my friend here.";
        
        
  controller.recipients = arrSelectedPhoneNumbers;
        NSLog(@"%@",controller.recipients);
  controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
  [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
 }

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532747/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-not-working ... You are missing many things here

Comment: You must google before posting question on SO!

Comment: hey i have used all the things but due to crietea of side it will not display..controller.recipients = arrSelectedPhoneNumbers is correct?

Comment: arrSelectedPhoneNumbers is the nsmutable array of multiple no's,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following way :

// Add delegate in .h file

```
@interface ContactsViewController : UIViewController<MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

// Add this in your .m file

```
 MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
                if(picker) {
                    picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;
                    picker.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:number];
                    picker.body = @"body content";
                    [self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil];
                    picker = nil;
                }
                NSLog(@"SMS fired");

    - (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {

            switch (result)
            {
                case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
                    NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
                    break;
                case MessageComposeResultSent:
                    NSLog(@"Result: sent");
                    break;
                case MessageComposeResultFailed:
                    NSLog(@"Result: failed");
                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
                    break;
            }
            //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```

Comment: can i pass directly the array? in picker.recipients=arrno?

Comment: Yes,you can pass array.First of all try to run code and debug it How its work. You can get clear idea about this thing.